# how to delete a document (by LongField) in lucene 4.10.0

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.10.0 and I wanna know how to delete a document by LongField. In practise I index documents that are identified by unique id (something like ISBN). I store the id with LongField :

```
doc.add(new LongField(Book.ID, item.getISBN(),Field.Store.YES));
```

How is possible to delete it by this unique id?

I know that for my version exist methods

```
 deleteDocuments(Query queries)

 deleteDocuments(Term terms)
```

of class IndexWriter, but the conscructor of Term doesn't allow Long value (and using the "trick" of parse long in String doesn't work) and with queries I'm not too much able. Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) to delete one or more documents. Set the long range accordingly, for that you want to use the `newLongRange` factory method.

Comment: I tryed with code you told me but the files .cfs are still in my directory (instead files .cfe and .si are deleted correctly) Is it correct or is there something wrong?

Comment: It is correct. Documents should be marked as deleted, and they should not show in query results.

Answer (score 2):

Simply transforming your Long to  string doesn't work because Lucene uses a special encoding for numeric types.  As such, you should use a query.  A [`NumericRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) specifically.  Something like:

```
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(Book.ID, item.getISBN(), item.getISBN(), true, true)
writer.deleteDocuments(query);
```

---

For a point of interest, in order to delete using terms, instead of a query, you would need to transform the numbers to lucene's prefix-coded string representation, using `NumericUtils`, something like:

```
BytesRefBuilder bytes = new BytesRefBuilder();
NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded(item.getISBN(), 0, bytes);
Term term = new Term(Book.ID, bytes.toBytesRef());
writer.deleteDocuments(term);
```

You generally shouldn't do that though.  `NumericUtils` is really only intended for internal use.  But perhaps it does elucidate why simple to-string approaches don't work.

Comment: Yes, I understood. It is a totally complete answer, but Diego has replied before you, so I can't mark this answer as "best". I'm sorry.